# How the tabs.open() function work with separate content script file?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, jpm, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am creating Firefox addons that works like search in chrome. How can i use browser.tabs.create() function with 'url' option?

I have read this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Tabs/create). But In here, there is no documentation of How to use this tab creation with variable url.

```js
//code for CMcontentScript.js-start 

 var tabs = require("../sdk/tabs");

self.on("click", function(node, data) {
     textContent = window.getSelection().toString();
     var searchURL = google.com?searchtid=" + textContent;
     
     tabs.open(searchURL);//In here i want to know how we can add variable url to 'url' option
 });
//code for CMcontentScript.js-ends


//code for index.js-start 

  searchMenu = cm.Item({
                    label: "Search With enadoc",
                    data: setURL,
                    context: cm.SelectionContext(),
                    image: self.data.url("./icon-16.png"),
                 contentScriptFile: "./CMcontentScript.js"
                });
//code for index.js-ends
```

[image]

Comment: ok so is it working for  hard corded url?

Comment: according to documentation u should parse a object .like `create({
     "url":searchURL 
   })`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are creating a JPM addon. Which is an SDK addon. This is not a WebExtension. And the `chrome.browser.tabs.create` is a webextension api.

To create a new tab you should do this:

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");


self.on("click", function(node, data) {
    var textContent = window.getSelection().toString();
    var searchURL = 'http://www.google.com?searchtid=' + textContent;

    tabs.open(searchURL);
});
```

Comment: this self on click method i added to separate file wich is included "data" folder, so i cant use this "var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");". there is a reference error shows in command promt.

Comment: @SameeraLiyanage can you put your code to github then share. You should be able to require the file in your data folder and it should work fine.